# regex that matches 1 character in quotes and special characters in quotes

Tags: regex

As the title suggests i need regex that matches 1 character inside quotes

`Example`: 'a' or '@' or '9'

But also matches the special characters in quotes :
`'\n', '\t', '\s'` etc..

basically the special characters which are 2 characters long surrounded with quotes

`'[^']'|'\n'|'\t'` this is what i thought of so far, but it does not match any of the '\n' etc... plus its not like i can keep placing or's for every special character.

An idea i thought now would be to just match everything that starts with `\` and is 2 characters long and surrounded by `''` but im confused on how to do it.

Comment: When dealing with backslashes, are you sure these are special characters and not simple characters? Try `'(?:\\[nt]|[^'])'`

Comment: Just to make sure: Do you want to match `'\x00'` or `'\u00FF'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this matches 'a' or '@' or '9' as well as '\n' or'\t'

```
'\\?.'
```

The question mark makes the \ an optional sign in this case. As already stated not any character only has one sign after \ so this won't work in all cases. However it works for your provided examples.

Comment: You are correct it does match all of them, thank you

Comment: Don't know your use case, but just to note: not every character could follow the backslash. E.g. `'\4'` will match the regex, but doesn't represent any character. On the other hand, as mentioned by @InSync, something like `'\x00'` is correct character definition, but won't match this regex.

Comment: I added your concern to the answer